# UIViewcontroller not releasing memory when moving to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

To keep things simple I've created a brand new project to test this out:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAbOm.jpg

View Controller scene links to LEVEL 1 scene.
LEVEL 1 scene links to View Controller scene

View Controller scene links to LEVEL 2 scene.
LEVEL 2 scene links to View Controller scene

LEVEL 1 and 2 have nothing to do with each other.

No code, just buttons and three view controllers.  All buttons are created via the storyboard, including segues.  Buttons are set as weak, but something is retaining/referencing the ViewControllers?  Hence I get the stair case:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPaHM.png
Nothing is released.  I get the same on a large project, too.

Doesn't matter if this is a semi small project with 1000 lines of code, or a brand new project with no code.  ViewControllers will not release from memory when going to another.

If the test project is brand new, what on earth could be retaining the ViewControllers in memory?  What am I missing?  I've only been doing this for two weeks, so I'm a little lost.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You are presenting the new view controller instances on top of the old ones, so they can't be released.  You would need to unwind back to the original view controller and present on that for level1 to be released.

Comment: @Paulw11.  Thank you for your answer.  But I honestly have no idea how to do that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Search for "unwind segue". That will explain how you can move back to an existing view controller.

Comment: @Paulw11.  Thank you.  I've read up and even followed this video on youtube:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akmPXZ4hDuU&list=PLX7qN3hyb14QO0FkJWibeVOlJM9BJy9zb&t=219s&index=125.  ViewControllers are still stuck in memory, unfortunately